# Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function AmazonAPI::construct(), 0 passed

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I getting this Error

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to
>   function AmazonAPI::__construct(), 0 passed in
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\amazon\index.php on line 151 and exactly 3 expected in
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\amazon\index.php:32 Stack trace: #0
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\amazon\index.php(151): AmazonAPI->__construct() #1

How can i Fix this problem please give me a solution

```
class AmazonAPI {

    public $amazon_aff_id;
    public $amazon_access_key;
    public $amazon_secret_key;

    public $url_params;
    public $itemID;
    public $xml;

    public $operation;
    public $signature;
    public $response_groups = "Small,Images,OfferSummary";

    public $error_message;
    public $error=0;


    public function __construct($affid, $access, $secret)
    {
        $this->amazon_aff_id = 'mybuyerxpo1-20';
        $this->amazon_access_key = 'AKIAJWDJOLXYKUI0000';
        $this->amazon_secret_key = 'XivGPw/aQfMGXcgi/BqR2F36hO/h1y3rjjfjoook';
    }

    public function build_url()
    {
        $url = "http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?";

        $this->response_groups = str_replace(",", "%2C", $this->response_groups);

        $url_params = "AWSAccessKeyId=" . $this->amazon_access_key;
        $url_params .= "&AssociateTag=" . $this->amazon_aff_id;

        if(!empty($this->itemID)) {
            $url_params .= "&ItemId=" . $this->itemID;
        }

        $url_params .= "&Operation=" . $this->operation;
        $url_params .= "&ResponseGroup=" . $this->response_groups;
        $url_params .= "&Service=AWSECommerceService";
        $url_params .= "&Timestamp=" . rawurlencode(gmdate("2019-10-01\ 16:26:45 UTC\Z"));
        $url_params .= "&Version=2019-10-01";

        $this->url_params = $url_params;

        $url .= $url_params;
        $url .= "&Signature=" . $this->generate_signature();

        return $url;
    }

    public function generate_signature()
    {
        $this->signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256",
            "GET\nwebservices.amazon.com\n/onca/xml\n" . $this->url_params,
            $this->amazon_secret_key, True));
        $this->signature = str_replace("+", "%2B", $this->signature);
        $this->signature = str_replace("=", "%3D", $this->signature);
        return $this->signature;
    }

    public function item_lookup($id)
    {
        $this->operation = "B07KW8SL6Z";
        $this->itemID = $id;

        $url = $this->build_url();

        $ch = curl_init();  

        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

        $output = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

        $this->xml = simplexml_load_string($output);
        return $this;
    }

    public function check_for_errors()
    {
        if(isset($this->xml->Error)) {
            $this->error_message = $this->xml->Error->Message;
            $this->error = 1;
        }
        if(isset($this->xml->Items->Request->Errors)) {
            $this->error_message = $this->xml->Items->Request->Errors->Error->Message;
            $this->error = 1;
        }
        return $this->error;
    }

    public function get_item_price($product)
    {
        $price = 0;
        if(isset($product->LowestNewPrice)) {
            $price = $product->LowestNewPrice->Amount;
        } elseif(isset($product->LowestUsedPrice)) {
            $price = $product->LowestUsedPrice->Amount;
        } elseif(isset($product->LowestCollectiblePrice)) {
            $price = $product->LowestCollectiblePrice->Amount;
        } elseif(isset($product->LowestRefurbishedPrice)) {
            $price = $product->LowestRefurbishedPrice->Amount;
        }
        return $price;
    }

    public function get_item_data()
    {
        if($this->check_for_errors()) return null;

        $product = $this->xml->Items->Item;
        $item = new STDclass;
        $item->detailedPageURL = $product->DetailPageURL;
        $item->link = "https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/".$this->itemID."/?tag=" . $this->amazon_aff_id;
        $item->title = $product->ItemAttributes->Title;
        $item->smallImage = $product->SmallImage->URL;
        $item->mediumImage = $product->MediumImage->URL;
        $item->largeImage = $product->LargeImage->URL;

        $item->price = $this->get_item_price($product->OfferSummary);

        return $item;
    }

}
```

Comment: if you assign default values to the 3 input parameters in the `__construct` method (ie: `__construct($affid=false,$access=false,$secret=false )` it should solve that issue

Comment: `__construct($affid, $access, $secret)` Those parameters are not used anywhere, so you could just remove them

Answer (score 1):

`public function __construct($affid, $access, $secret)` : your constructor requires 3 parameters : `$affid`, `$access` and `$secret` but you don't use them.

Replace your constructor per `__construct()`, without any parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than hardcoding the sensitive details into your class you assign default values to the parameters and then supply the values for these parameters at runtime.

The same idea can be used for other methods that have a parameter, for instance the `item_lookup` currently has an `$id` attribute but it looks as if you might assign another parameter there for `$operation` ( unless that never changes )

```
public function __construct( $affid=false, $access=false, $secret=false ){
    if( $affid && $access && $secret ){
        $this->amazon_aff_id = $affid;
        $this->amazon_access_key = $access;
        $this->amazon_secret_key = $secret;
    } else {
        trigger_error('Affid, Access and Secret are required');
    }
}
```

So when the class is invoked you would do something like:

```
error_reporting( E_ALL );

$affid = 'mybuyerxpo1-20';
$access = 'AKIAJWDJOLXYKUIB537A';
$secret = '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';

$app=new AmazonAPI( $affid, $access, $secret );
```

Comment: $app=new AmazonAPI( $affid, $access, $secret );
echo $app->get_item_data();

I am getting following Error 

Recoverable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in F:\xampp\htdocs\amazon\index.php on line 170

Comment: What / where is `$this->itemID` assigned in your implementation of the above? You cannot use `echo` to output an object, use `print_r` or `var_dump`

Comment: yes I used var_dump in object. I am getting nothing. Do you think this API is deactivate ?  

AmazonAPI Object ( [amazon_aff_id] => mybuyerxpo1-20 [amazon_access_key] => AKIAJF7UYAI77UYKZONA [amazon_secret_key] => 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 [url_params] => [itemID] => [xml] => [operation] => [signature] => [response_groups] => Small,Images,OfferSummary [error_message] => [error] => 0 )

Comment: No - the Amazon API is still active but I am unable to test as I do not have an Amazon api key etc ( presumably the details given are not the real ones !? )

Comment: I was chat with amazon support they said API is active. But why i cant data using this script. can you run this script in your local pc ?

Comment: When I run `$app=new AmazonAPI( $affid, $access, $secret ); `and then call `$app->get_item_data();` I get loads of errors

Comment: Are you absolutely confident that you are generating the correct signature string? Have you tested your code with the default test values offered here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/rest-signature.html

Comment: my script is wrong. I was check this another amazon API. I am confused how to write such as script

Comment: I discovered a useful resource on the amazon site that helps build the query - which will help fix flaws in your code http://associates-amazon.s3.amazonaws.com/scratchpad/index.html

Comment: I wrote some code which seems to work but I am unable to fully test because I do not qualify to apply for access to the Product Advertising API so always get a `"Your AccessKey Id is not registered for Product Advertising API."` error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39815540/product-advertising-api-php-invalid-xml-response

At first I used this code any. But recently this is not working. @Ramraider can you check this script

Comment: using the code I wrote and testing with the credentials you gave ( which you ought to change asap btw ) yields a `"AWS Access Key ID: AKIAxxxyyyzzz37A. You are submitting requests too quickly. Please retry your requests at a slower rate."` error. Research shows this error is related to sales ( or more specifically ) a lack of sales within last 30days. Apparently `" generating sales via SiteStripe should get you access."`